# Hpux -lq and -lm

Tags: hp-ux

Simple and nice question about hpux
In case of emergency i can boot with two options

```
-lq
-lm
```

I know -lq is lost quorum on mirror,ok
And -lm?Is lost mirror?What the difference with -lq?

Comment: Maybe useful : http://www2.fiu.edu/~tho01/psg/hpux.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found

```
lm = maintenance mode
```

Comment: More specifically, `-lm` is **LVM** maintenance mode: it allows you to do things to the system volume group (usually `vg00` but may be different) that would normally require deactivating the volume group.